# Scan Php code looking for Gettext

Tags: php, gettext

I need to generate **.po** files for the **Php** code of my web application. This is a very large application that needs to be translated to 
several different languages. So far, I have been using **PoEdit** in order to generate my **.po** files. The problem lies in that many
of my files lack the Gettext notation **echo _("message")** and in the past I only used **echo "message"**.

This is what I think it could be the best solution for my issue:

1. Create a script that scans my Php code and tells me which of my messages are being and not being displayed using **Gettext**. How would I do this?
2. Replace those string not using **Gettext** with the appropriate **Gettext** pattern.

Can you please advise me what is the best aproach in order to get all my code using **Gettext** that I should look to?

Comment: There's hardly an automated way to do this. Unless you have very specific limitations on your coding style, it's almost impossible to distiguish the strings that need translation from those that don't programmatically. A nice round of manual i18n is probably necessary.

Comment: @deceze what is a round of manual i18n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one way how to convert echoing messages without translation by gettext to echoing messages with translation by gettext:

If you know that all messages are *represented* by only one variable, for example `$Message`, following way will be made relatively fast, else you would have to find all used echoing of any messages ... and do that manually (mostly if message is only one - and it is represented by text, not by variable holding that text).

In your editor to start global search (in all files) and then, to go file by file and use replacing - and set `$Message` for search and `_($Message)` for replacement ... unless your editor allows replacing in more files at the same time. Then you would do all replacement at one time.

I would not suggest to do this replacing directly in php.

Comment: `_($Message)` is not helpful at all. Encapsulating variables in the gettext function does not allow the string to be extracted. `_()` can/should only be used on string literals.